# how to restrict my textarea to overflow beyond certain rows?

Tags: html, textarea

i am working with textarea in that i don't want scroll bar while increasing the number of rows. It should be resizable. Is there any possible way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to increase the height of the `textarea` as the user enters more text.

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0],
    originalHeight = textarea.clientHeight;

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    textarea.style.height = Math.max(textarea.scrollHeight, originalHeight) + 'px';
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxPuf/).

It doesn't seem to want to shrink with that example code. I think most people who write these controls produce a hidden `div` with `height: auto` and all the font styles copied over (`font-size`, `font-family`, `line-height`, `letter-spacing`, etc) and then update the `div`'s inner text with the `textarea`'s contents. It then sets the `textarea`'s height based on the height of this hidden element.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable info.